# Javascript/JQuery Calculation of Dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to achieve something like this. A HTML view has a finite number of images (shown as red boxes in the image below). Are there any browser/jQuery APIs available today (cross-browser) which will let me calculate the dimensions of the remaining space (shown in green boxes) quickly? In the example shown below, it is easy to calculate the green area dimensions using simple geometry given the dimensions of the red boxes. But I am talking about very complex scenarios and complicated combination of images.

[image: Reference Image]

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually need dimensions of white-space, or do you just need the total number of pixels that are empty?

Comment: I need the exact position and dimension of each green block.

Comment: Are you the person in control of where the images are drawn?

Comment: Yes. As i said, i know the location and dimension of all the images.

Comment: Ah well if you know that, then you just need to use Mathematics to figure it out. The point I was making was that you cannot trust the dimensions / coordinates the browser gives you, if that's how you are getting those values. If you are getting them from elsewhere you can ignore my canvas advice I guess. And like I said actually working out the green boxes dimensions isn't a programming question, so this is the wrong place to be asking it.

Answer (score 0):

If you every images have absolute property, you can calculate dimension through top and left properties like `$('#elementID').offset().top` and `$('#elementID').offset().left`

Answer (score 0):

From my experience working with DOM element dimensions, you cannot rely on them for exact values, and certainly can't really on them for the same values cross-browser. You can get OK results, but if you have complex scenarios then you will probably come undone at some point.

One way I have achieved similar things in the past is by drawing images to HTML5 Canvas. Using `canvas` you can have very fine-grained control. I have even iterated canvases pixel-by-pixel to get pixel perfect measurements of items on the canvas.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-size/) for a brief overview of drawing an image.

**UPDATE**

There is no easy way to do it. Using this method is low-level and will require you to use mathematics, and possibly byte-level image data from the canvas. However, if your problem is as complex as you suggest then you will have to get stuck in. When I did something similar I was also looking for an easy way to achieve what I wanted in the browser, then spent a month getting to grips with the canvas API, learning about byte-level colour data etc, but in then end I got what I needed, and ended up with something quite unique as it was difficult to achieve in a browser.

To get started, first I would say look at implementing a layered canvas by absolutely positioning multiple canvases on top of each other, then drawing a single image on each one. You already know the sizes of the images, and you can decide the coordinates of where to draw the image, so that's a start. In fact that may be all you need, you can track each image as you draw them by storing coords and dimensions, and you should be able to build up an accurate picture in numbers of where all your images are in 2D space.

Using those numbers you should then be able to calculate any empty spaces on there. However, that is a beyond me and probably a question for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (which is actually down at the moment :D).

Comment: Given the images and the absolute position and size of each - if i draw each image on a canvas according to the position and size of each image, can I get the dimensions and positions of the space remaining in the canvas (the green blocks)? How can i get the dimension and position of the green blocks if I go this route?

Comment: I don't get it - if I have to eventually turn to mathematics to calculate the empty spaces, why do I bother to draw all the images on canvas at all? If i have to involve mathematics, I can just work with the numbers (dimension/position of images) and write a complex algorithm to figure out the empty space. What is your point in drawing on canvas then?